# Golang Goroutines - Fix Race Condition using Atomic Functions

Tags: go, atomic, race-condition, goroutine

I am a newbie in Golang and I am trying to understand the goroutines.
Here is the piece of code which I got from https://www.golangprograms.com/goroutines.html.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
    "sync/atomic"
)

var (
    counter int32          // counter is a variable incremented by all goroutines.
    wg      sync.WaitGroup // wg is used to wait for the program to finish.
)

func main() {
    wg.Add(3) // Add a count of two, one for each goroutine.

    go increment("Python")
    go increment("Java")
    go increment("Golang")

    wg.Wait() // Wait for the goroutines to finish.
    fmt.Println("Counter:", counter)

}

func increment(name string) {
    defer wg.Done() // Schedule the call to Done to tell main we are done.

    for range name {
        fmt.Println("name:", name)
        fmt.Println("Counter in range:", counter)
        atomic.AddInt32(&counter, 1)
        runtime.Gosched() // Yield the thread and be placed back in queue.
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
name: Golang
Counter in range: 0
name: Java
Counter in range: 1
name: Golang
Counter in range: 2
name: Golang
Counter in range: 3
name: Java
Counter in range: 4
name: Golang
Counter in range: 5
name: Python
Counter in range: 6
name: Java
Counter in range: 7
name: Golang
Counter in range: 8
name: Java
Counter in range: 9
name: Golang
Counter in range: 10
name: Python
Counter in range: 11
name: Python
Counter in range: 12
name: Python
Counter in range: 13
name: Python
Counter in range: 14
name: Python
Counter in range: 15
Counter: 16
```

I am unable to understand that why the output is 16. Even we added only 3 goroutines. Shouldn't it be 3?

Can anyone please explain me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> I am unable to understand that why the output is 16. Even we added only 3 goroutines. Shouldn't it be 3?

Why should it be 3? It should be as many times `atomic.AddInt32(&counter, 1)` is called.

How many times is that? You launch 3 goroutines, and each has a loop. Incrementing is done inside the loops.

The loops:

```
for range name {}
```

The `for range` over a `string` iterates over the runes of the `string`. The names in your case are `Golang`, `Java` and `Python`. So the loop bodies will be executed as many times as many runes these strings have: 6 for `Golang`, 4 for `Java` and 6 for `Python`, that adds up to 16.

Comment: I overlooked the `range` function. Thank you so much for the explanation. It's clear to me now.

Comment: can you please provide me with some useful links or tutorials to learn Golang? I just started Golang yesterday and struggling with some good stuff.

Comment: The official homepage and its links are a good place to start: https://golang.org

Answer (score 0):

You are range over the given input string, trange treat it as an array and iterates over it.
See this example

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    increment("test")
    increment("test_dev")
    increment("test_deploy")
    
}

func increment(name string) {
    for i, value := range name {
        fmt.Printf("name: %s index: %d, char: %c\n", name, i, value)

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know how range works. I just missed the range functionality in my example.